# Reducing JQuery Size by Removing Unnecessary Functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using only fadeIn and fadeOut from jQuery and I don't want to load the whole jQuery. Is there any way to remove other functions? I know that minified version of jquery is really small but 1KB matters in my case.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't go around deleting things out of the jQuery pack

Comment: use jquery minified versions or see the documentation for fadeIn and fadeOut and write your own functions...that may solve your problem

Comment: Are you compressing the response from your server? Seems like wasted effort to hack apart the library just to save 1KB.

Comment: @you can use google CDN for fast load if yours e-commerce site or so , we use akamai for the same....

Comment: @gov you mean I use settimeout to write my own fadeIn and fadeOut !?

Comment: @AliBZ , yeah .if you want only two functions...

Comment: @AliBZ Yes, you should. They aren't that complicated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is part of the decision on whether to use a javascript framework or not.  Every framework contains a base, and that base should not be interfered with.  If you edit the core of a framework, you've essentially removed the primary benefit of using the framework to begin with.  Now, you cannot update when new versions are released without re-hacking the framework again.

If size is a key consideration in your project, then it was a bad decision to include a framework that you apparently barely needed.  Next time, you'll know to base this decision on more than a handful of novelty effects. :)

Comment: A tough answer but fair in my opinion.

Comment: This is, IMO, the worst thing about widely-distributed frameworks.  It gives beginners the idea that the "best way" to have neat feature/effect X is to include a complete framework.  They didn't want the FRAMEWORK, they wanted the FEATURE - two different things entirely.  Now you're saddled with a ton of code that you don't use or need, and all the inherent bugs and security flaws that come with it.  I'm looking at you, Drupal.

Comment: I would agree and look to write my own based on jQuery as the base you can also remove the need for Sizzle if you don't need the selectors which should save you some size.

Comment: I absolutely disagree. Avoiding jQuery just because you don't intend to use 100% of it is sillyness. There are virtually no cases where you *actually* need to save a single KB of minimized jQuery per session. In the vast majority of cases, you should include jQuery from a CDN, regardless of how much or little of it you need, and get on with your life rather than rewriting any part of it yourself.

Comment: Using an entire framework for 'feature x' rather than because you want to use the framework itself is wrong-headed.  I am not saying it is only worth using a framework if you use ALL of it.  I am saying that you should be using a framework because you're using a framework, not because you want to fade elements (for example).  Fading elements is a **feature** of jQuery, not a reason to use jQuery.

Comment: @Chris Wanting to fade elements in/out is a *great* reason to use jQuery. There is literally no up-side to writing your own code to do this.

Comment: I disagree.  The decision to use a framework should be a top-level project decision. No framework can be the simple solution to every problem.  It does not make sense to bloat your project with excess code if you can solve the problem directly without a framework.  Adding jQuery **just so you can have fade** is just poor practice.

Comment: I agree with meagar. If I want to use Ajax and fading, I don't think it is a good idea to write it on my own. the purpose of using jquery is to easily do somethings that are not easy to write or other reasons.

Comment: OK, here's the scenario.  You need to fade an element.  You can write a cross-browser function to fade an element in about 10 lines of code. Including jQuery instead adds thousands of lines of code - this is the very definition of bloat.  Now take another step, you need to do AJAX and fade elements.  Writing a basic AJAX function (or using the built-in XHR object vanilla) can be accomplished in another 10 lines of code.  So: 20 lines of your own code, or 20,000 lines by someone else?  Don't get me wrong - I like frameworks.  I **use** frameworks.  But only when I **need** a framework.

Comment: It's 2021, someone upvoted this; I am working on a project where I had to temporarily bump up the JS bundle budget because here in the future, we use npm packages, and importing 10 megs of other people's code is standard practice. I clearly lost this battle and war haha. But, I still roll my own stuff when I am working on embedded systems.

Comment: People automate stripping libraries like Bootstrap to make it smaller it you could do the with jQuery then it makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

No, you should absolutely not attempt to hack out the parts of jQuery you don't need. Someday you might want to upgrade to the latest jQuery, or add some small bit of functionality to your site that depends on something you removed. You'll either spend a lot of time undoing your changes or start fresh and have to hack out the unwanted stuff again.

There are far more effective ways of making jQuery load faster and with less bandwidth. Do what the jQuery website itself does and use a CDN. Taken directly from the source at [jquery.com](http://www.jquery.com):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Chances are very good this file will be cached by the browser. No amount of hacking/minifying will equal the speed gains you'll get by loading the file from the browser's cache. It is simply the easiest and most effective way to load jQuery quickly.

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion too, older versions of jquery are smaller. You lose some features but can still utilize a lot of the benefits with a smaller footprint. Take jquery 1.2.3:

> URL:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js
>   Title:    No title found Date:    Report run
>   on Fri Feb 18 13:43:55 EST 2011
>   Total Size:   15958 bytes

Vs 1.5.0:

> URL:  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js
>   Title:    No title found  Date:Report run
>   on Fri Feb 18 13:46:10 EST 2011
>   Diagnosis  Global Statistics   Total
>   Size: 29466 bytes

Answer (score 1):

If you are using one or two features of a framework better try to write your own function which can fulfill your need, this way, you will gain experience as well as full control over the function