# include jQuery partially

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I only want to use $(document).ready or some other utility from jQuery and do not want to include the whole library. Is there ways?

Are there any alternatives to below usage?

```
<head>
.
.
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
.
.
</head>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "partially"?

Comment: if you only need it a little here or there, maybe just use Vanilla JS?

Comment: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/  or use the `slim` [build](https://jquery.com/download/) (but know what's not in it)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reducing JQuery Size by Removing Unnecessary Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044985/reducing-jquery-size-by-removing-unnecessary-functions)

Comment: document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});  ...you don't need jQuery at all to use "ready"

Comment: Frankly, I don't see why this was closed...it is VERY CLEAR what the questions author is asking for.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO thank you, because of this post, I cannot post another question on stackoverflow, it says I have not been asking questions properly so I am restricted. :(

Comment: @YunusGedik Try deleting this question altogether...then it MIGHT let you post more.  The issue you are experiencing is yet another reason why I (personally) HATE Stackoverflow.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO it says, I cannot delete this, because others have invested time and effort into answering it. It is a real-life deadlock. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your own copy of jQuery with (at least partially) only the functionality you need, and use that. The GitHub repo has [this to say about it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery#modules):

> **Modules**
>
> Special builds can be created that exclude subsets of jQuery functionality. This allows for smaller custom builds when the builder is certain that those parts of jQuery are not being used. For example, an app that only used JSONP for `$.ajax()` and did not need to calculate offsets or positions of elements could exclude the offset and ajax/xhr modules.
>
> Any module may be excluded except for `core`, and `selector`. To exclude a module, pass its path relative to the `src` folder (without the `.js` extension).

Or coming at it the other way, if you only need a small set of functionality, a lot of it is fairly easily replicated these days using modern browser APIs such as `querySelectorAll` [[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll)] (for finding elements), [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) (for event delegation), [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) (for ajax), etc. along with modern JavaScript features ([iterability](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) in particular is handy, since one of jQuery's strengths is its set-based approach).